# How to serialize single-valued @Data object using Jackson without nesting (e.g. {"id":123}, not {"id":{"value":123}})?

Tags: java, json, jackson, lombok

I'm planning to use Lombok for creating hundreds of classes that are based on "value object" pattern as follows:

```
@Data
public final class SomeId implements Serializable {
    private final long value;
}
```

And I want to use these classes for JSON serialization powered by Jackson. for example, consider a DTO class as follows:

```
public class SomeDTO {
    SomeId id;
    public SomeId getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

I want that DTO class to be serialized as something like `{"id":123}`, but Jackson produces something like `{"id":{"value":123}}`, which comes with unnecessary nested object with a field named `value`. i.e. a testcase expresses my requirement:

```
public class SomeDTOTest {
    @Test
    public void serializationTest() throws Exception {
        SomeDTO dto = new SomeDTO();
        dto.id = new SomeId(123);

        String serialized = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(dto);

        System.out.println(serialized);             // {"id":{"value":123}}
        assertThat(serialized, is("{\"id\":123}")); // I want {"id":123} instead!
    }
}
```

I know putting `@JsonValue` annotation to every `getValue()` method in `SomeId` classes would be a solution, but I can't do it because there is no actual definition of `@Data` classes because Lombok automatically creates it.

Creating actual `getValue()` method annotated as `@JsonValue` for every classes by hand might be another solution but it means creating tons of boilarplate code.

How do I achieve this requirement without boilerplate code?

Comment: There is 1 more way, but i don't know if it will be any help for you: `public class SomeDTO { @JsonUnwrapped SomeId id;}` and
`public class SomeId { @JsonProperty(value = "id") private long value;}`

Comment: You can simply annotate the value field in the SomeId class with @JsonValue. You don't need to annotate the getter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write custom Serializer for this class.

E.g.:

```
class CustomSerializer extends StdSerializer<SomeId>{

    protected CustomSerializer(Class<SomeId> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(SomeId someId, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeNumber(someId.getValue()); 
    }   
}
```

Now use this serializer to serialize `SomeId` class:

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

 SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
 module.addSerializer(new CustomSerializer(SomeId.class));       
 mapper.registerModule(module);

 SomeDTO dto = new SomeDTO();
 dto.id = new SomeId(123);     
 String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(dto);
 System.out.println(serialized);             // output : {"id":123}
```

Comment: Nice, but with your solution it seems that I need to create hundreds of `CustomSerializer`s for all of "value object" classes - it would be another boilerplate code which I want to eliminate. creating a parent class for "value object" classes may be an option, but I would rather avoid it because it reduces benefit of using Lombok.

Answer (score 5):

I created an interface which has `getValue()` which annotated as `@JsonValue`:

```
public interface LongValue {
    @JsonValue
    long getValue();
}
```

Then implemented it in every `@Data` classes. note that actual implementation of `getValue()` will be automatically generated by Lombok:

```
@Data
public final class SomeId implements LongValue, Serializable {
    private final long value;
}
```

With that I've got the test `SomeDTOTest` passed - `SomeDTO` is serialized to `{"id":123}` as I expected.